# How to copy a build phase to another target in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, build, copy

I have a *Copy Bundle Resources* build phase which contains 200 resources. And now I have to make a new target as different kind. (app -> static lib) So unfortunately, I can't just duplicate the target :(

Anyway it's nonsense adding each resources one-by-one by hand. I tried to duplicate them at once but all I did failed. I made a new window and tried to drag them into the new target's phase, but it didn't worked.

How can I copy the *Copy Bundle Resources* build phase to another target? The target is in same project, so there is no file referencing problem.

Comment: Have you tried duplicating the target and then setting `NewTarget->Build Settings->Linking->Mach-O Type` to `Static Library` and `NewTarget->Build Settings->Deployment->SkipInstall` to `NO`?

Comment: I tried the above approach, but Xcode complains that I've set the type incorrectly (i.e. static library).  There are also a variety of other settings I tried to convert on my duplicated target, but nothing has seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I'd have a crack at comparing the binary of project file and see if you can copy and paste it in. try one first and see if you can replicate it.

Comment: Eonil: If you ever solved this, maybe you could ANSWER your own question. Unanswered questions are less helpful. If you've found a solution, please share it!

Comment: @WarrenP I didn't tried this after 2012, so I don't know working answer. As far as I remember, the last partially working workaround was selecting the files and using *Reveal in Project Navigator* menu on the context menu of file list of the phase. This sometimes worked, but easily fails if I have a lot of files.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by opening my `.pbxproj` file in a text editor and doing some hunting for the right lines related to my target.

It's tricky, because Xcode uses a system of ids to populate the project file (ps. I did this while migrating from Cocoapods to Carthage, so I'm not using that setup)

It takes a little work finding the id of your target, but in Xcode 9, you should have something similar to

`targets = (
    EDBC6D6D1E0150850033868B /* target 1 */,
    EDF960C71E1963E0001A29CE /* fancy target */,
    EDF960D71E196DF3001A29CE /* Service Extension */,
);`

in the `/* Begin PBXProject section */` section that describes the project. Search the `.pbxproj` file for your id to find the similarly structured `buildPhases` that lists ids for your targets build phases.

`buildPhases = (
    47120FBF1F4343A900C27821 /* Sources */,
    4712100B1F4343A900C27821 /* Frameworks */,
    4712100D1F4343A900C27821 /* Resources */,
    471210251F4343A900C27821 /* ShellScript */,
    476673451F5F1ACD00567450 /* Embed App Extensions */,
);`

Now, find where the required id (in OPs case, Resources) and you'll find the list of resources. You can compare these to the list of your source target and copy and paste.

Comment: Thank you so much! Only thing that I used that really worked in Xcode 10

Answer (score 0):

What version of Xcode?  Did the new target start as a template, or empty?

What does it mean for a static library to have a "copy bundle resources" build phase?  Wouldn't it would use the resources of the thing that it's linked into?

Comment: It's hard to remember what I'd do with this question at this time. Because I am not on the project with this issue. Also, this is an old question about Xcode in 2012. (maybe version 4.x) Xcode has been changed a lot after that, so this question may not appropriate for current version of Xcode.